# Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected spaces, then $X\times Y$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, connectedness, continuous-homomorphisms

I have 2 questions about this proof of connected topological spaces.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected spaces, then $X\times Y$ is connected.

Proof. Let $p=(x_1,y_1)\in X\times Y,q=(x_2,y_2)\in X\times Y.$

Notice that $\{x_1\}\times Y\approx  Y,X\times\{y_2\}\approx X.$

Hence $\{x_1\}\times Y$ and $X\times\{y_2\}$ are connected.

Also notice $\{x_1\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_2\}$ is connected and $p,q\in\{x_1\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_2\},$ i.e. $p$ and $q$ belong to the same component. But $p$ and $q$ were chosen arbitrarily; hence $X\times Y$ has only one component-itself.

Therefore we must have $\{x_1\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_2\}= X\times Y,$ i.e. $X\times Y$ is connected.

---

What's the homeomorphism that should be consider in the proof ? **and**

Does the last equality  is well justified?

Comment: Why do you think the proof should consider a homeomorphism?

Comment: @LeeMosher to go from $\{x_1\}\times Y$ to  $Y$, and from $X\times\{y_2\}$ to $X$

Comment: You just need to consider $p_{1}\colon \{x_{1}\}\times Y \longrightarrow Y$ defined by $p_{1}(x_{1},y)=y$.

Comment: And $\{x_{1}\}\times Y \cup X \times \{y_{2}\}$ is not equal to $X\times Y$. For example, if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, $x_{1}=y_{2}=0$, $(1,1)\in X\times Y$, but $(1,1)\notin \{x_{1}\}\times Y \cup X \times \{y_{2}\}$.

Comment: @Laura I edited my question, can't I say $\{x_1\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_2\}= X\times Y$ ?

Comment: You can say that $\bigcup( \{x_{1}\} \times Y \cup X\times \{y_{2}\})=X\times Y.$ Are you trying to prove that statement by yourself or you are trying to understand it?

Comment: @Laura Both things, I didn't write this proof and I don't know where is it from neither. The only thing I added to the proof was $\{x_1\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_2\}= X\times Y$ which I thought it was a consequence of the of the whole argument above.

Comment: @Laura So I just change this $( \{x_{1}\} \times Y \cup X\times \{y_{2}\})=X\times Y$ by this $\bigcup( \{x_{1}\} \times Y \cup X\times \{y_{2}\})=X\times Y.$ ? And then the proof will be correct, right?

Comment: @bella Have you learned that if $X$ and $Y$ are connected and $X\cap Y\neq \varnothing$, then $X\cup Y$ is connected?

Comment: @Laura yes I know that

Answer (score 1):

I would write the proof in the following way:

Let $p=(x_{1},y_{1})$, $q=(x_{2},y_{2})\in X\times Y$.

$\{x_{1}\}\times Y$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, by the homeomorphism $p_{1} \colon \{x_{1}\}\times Y \longrightarrow Y$ defined as $p_{1}(x_{1},y)=y$. Similarly, $X\times \{y_{2}\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$. Then, since being connected is a topological property, $\{x_{1}\}\times Y$ and $X\times \{y_{2}\}$ are connected. Then, $\{x_{1}\}\times Y \cup X\times \{y_{2}\}$ is connected, because both are connected and the intersection is not empty ($(x_{1},y_{2})$ is in the intersection).

Finally, $X\times Y=\bigcup(\{x_{1}\}\times Y \cup X\times \{y_{2}\})$. Note that this union is also connected because of the same reason.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: So in the proof that I wrote the 'component argument' is useless?

Comment: I think so. You are saying that $p$ and $q$ belong to the same connected component, $\{x_{1}\}\times Y\cup X\times \{y_{2}\}$, and that $p$ and $q$ are arbitrary, so that it has a unique connected component. However, $\{x_{1}\}\times Y\cup X\times \{y_{2}\}$  depends on $p$ and $q$, so that argument is not valid.

Comment: @bella I think it is quite valid, and I found it convincing.  The pattern is a very common one in mathematical proofs when we want to show that something is unique.  You might phrase it this way:  Suppose we have two components, say $C_1$ and $C_2$.  Let $p\in C_1$ and $q\in C_2$.  Then argue  as you did and conclude that $p$ and $q$ are in the same component, and therefore $C_1 = C_2$. But your final claim, “we must have $\{x_1\}\times Y\cup X\times\{y_2\}= X\times Y,$” is false, and I don't understand where you got it from.

Comment: @MJD So a proof is needed to see that $p$ and $q$ belong to the same component? . :D The final claim came from my intelligence.

Comment: @bella Yes, a proof is needed to see that $p$ and $q$ belong to the same component, and the proof you gave in your question seems adequate to me.